# How to indicate the code origin of a function call within another code in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have the directory of R codes that looks like this:

```
--- main_shiny_app
   |
   |_ src
   |    |_ code1.R # contains: function1(), function2()
   |    |_ code2.R # contains: function_x(), function_y()
   |
   |
   |_ index.Rmd # Shiny app.
```

Currently `index.Rmd` I call the `function1()` in `code1.R` this way:

```
source("./src/code1.R")
function1()
```

It gets confusing when I call more functions from code1.R. I need a way
to indicate the source of those function in the line of code itself.

My question is what should I do so that I can do it this way in `index.Rmd`:

```
 code1::function1()
```

At this moment I don't plan to make a full fledge R package into CRAN etc. 
I just want to have a clear way the origins of the functions in main.R.

---

Some thing like this can be done in Python:

```
# In main.py calling a function in code1.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/absolute_path_to/src/')
import code1 
code1.function1()
```

Comment: Repeat after me please: Create. A. Package.   That has nothing to do with CRAN, but *everything* with the best way to organize your code.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: You mean turn `src` into a package inside `main_dir` ?

Comment: R really needs you to do a package for this. You could use your own environments to isolate symbols, but is really not worth it for your use case. The overhead of writing a package is small with devtools and roxygen2.

Comment: I'd also recommend creating a package. If you skeleton a package, the cost is really small.  What you need to do is to put a script with functions in /R/ directory and build (which is just a click in RStudio).

Comment: @amatsuo_net Does it have to be named `/R/` directory or can I use `src/` as in OP. What specific RStudio button are you referring to? Based on my directory structure above what's the sequence in RStudio to achieve your suggestion?

Comment: This less than 2min video provides enough information to start package development. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScV7XXlBZww If you open two instances of RStudio (one for actual data analyses and another for package development), things are even easier.